# The Electorate badge doesn't work well on Unix & Linux

Tags: discussion, support, status-bydesign, badges

I noticed my next badge section and is not consistent with the others stack-exchange sites:

[image]

[image]

Electorate vote description says: Vote on 600 questions[both questions and answers] and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

Here I think is taken into consideration just the number of questions instead of the total number of votes

Answer (score 8):

I don't see where you found the parenthetical (both questions and answers). The description of the Electorate badge is

> Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions.

So, one needs to satisfy both requirements:

1. At least 600 votes on questions
2. Out of all votes on questions and answers, at least 25% are on questions